# How to put a url citation on the bottom of beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, urls

I need to insert a citation at the bottom of the slide. However, the website address includes underline. Therefore, it treats the underline as subscript. How can I work this out?[image]

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \footnote{http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic_civ_eng.pdf}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. After I use the command \url, how can I put the link at the bottom?@jon

Comment: @jon please, can you write your suggestion like response? ... @Windy, I think @jon suggestion requires `url` package ...

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to note.

1. Underscores, in general, must be escaped in order to show up properly outside of math mode. If this is surprising, you may well find reading at least the first parts of the [*The Com­pre­hen­sive LaTeX Sym­bol List*](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en) worth your time.
2. The `beamer` class loads `hyperref` by default, and, if you want to use a command like `\url`, then you can "escape" those underscores, but it is not necessary....

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\footnote{http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic\_civ\_eng.pdf}
\footnote{\url{http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic\_civ\_eng.pdf}}
% Compare:
\footnote{\url{http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic_civ_eng.pdf}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Thus: If you are writing a URL and are relying only on the `url` package (not an issue with `beamer` unless you try to do so), then you should *not* escape the underscores in a `\url` command. But if you are writing URLs, you should probably also load `hyperref`, and in that case, the output is the same whether you escape them or not. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip 10pt \parindent 0pt
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

% OK:
http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic\_civ\_eng.pdf

% Not OK if only `url.sty` is loaded; OK if hyperref.sty` is
% loaded, or both are:
\url{http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic\_civ\_eng.pdf}

% OK if either `url.sty` or `hyperref.sty` (or both) are loaded:
\url{http://www.pprime.fr/sites/default/files/pictures/d3/fic_civ_eng.pdf}
\end{document}
```